# Vue content/code not showing after importing

Tags: vue.js

The path is correct, it just doesn't show any code in App.vue. I'm completely new to vue so I have no idea what is going wrong at the moment, any help would be amazing!

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import test from './components/test.vue'
</script>

<template>
      
</template>
```

test.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <button @click="changeMessage">Change Message</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello, Vue!"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeMessage() {
      this.message = "Message changed!";
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You should put your component into the template:

```
<script setup>
import test from './components/test.vue'
</script>

<template>
   <test />   
</template>
```

Comment: @Vyrncoding don't forget to accept the answer (the checkbox). that way i will be rewarded and motivated to help you with Vue in the future, thanks

Comment: did it I think, sorry for the late response